# Flutter Navigator Page Change within async button press

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, exception, navigation

I'm experimenting with flutter and now I reached a point, where I don't understand, why I get an exception. I already tried a few things.

What am I doing?

I'm pressing a button - this button executes an async function within unpressed handler. Inside, depending on the response, I want to change the page.

```
TextButton(
  child: Text(
    _title,
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () async {
    var response = await authBloc.onLogin(_akey, _password);

    if (response.isValid) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Container(),
      ));
    }
  },
),
```

For me it looks fine. I even tried to do this within a scheduled binder (SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)), but I'm getting the same exception.

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried your widget definition and not getting any exceptions  you mentioned, perhaps you could add the whole class instead so that we could check what's wrong with the parent widget or on the build method.

Comment: It took me some time, but I got it working. The issue was, that the handling was inside a component, and the parent changed. I fixed it with adding a function call, after log in, that is called, so the parent widget gets the "callback", once completed and the state is safe.